# SQL Server equivalent for Oracle's Table.Column(+) = value

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, database-migration

I am working on a project that deals with migration of Oracle db to SQL Server. I came across a query like:

```
select <colums>
from Table1, Table2
where Table1.key = Table2.Key(+)
      and Table1.Column1(+) = 1234
```

I know the SQL server equivalent of query upto first where condition is

```
select <colums>
from Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Key = Table2.Key
WHERE ....
```

My question is what do I need to write for the condition

```
and Table1.Column1(+) = 1234
```

will simply

```
and Table1.Column1 = 1234
```

work, since I think the join part I've already covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select <colums>
from Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Key = Table2.Key
WHERE Table1.Column1 = 1234
```